# want use a submit handler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an HTML file. I want to use submit handler that must call custom.js in custom.js the contact.php is called

Html

```
<div id="submit"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Send</button></div>
```

---

jQuery

```
$('#submit').submit(function(e) {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'contact.php',
           data: $('#participants-summary').serialize(),
           success: function(data) {
              alert('ajaxdone');
           }

        });
        e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: what's wrong w/ your code?

Comment: Hi friend i dont no how to use submit handler., so i want to use it in my index.html using post method ...must also use jquery plugin validation., i stuck

Comment: using ajax jquery ., this code not working

Comment: check the Jamie Wilson answer. i think thats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the jQuery submit handler to be attached to a form. So

```
<div id="submit">
```

needs to become

```
<form id="submit">
```

for

```
$("#submit").submit(
```

to work

Comment: the solution is working but the data is not inserting into databse

Comment: That is probably a bigger issue you need to detail in another question. There are a large number of things that could be causing that in your server side code.

Comment: i have file index.html contact.php, using submit handler i am calling contact.php still its not working

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Send</button>
     <script>
    $('#submit').submit(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'contact.php',
                data: $('#participants-summary').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('ajaxdone');
                }

            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
 </script>

Comment: if($session6 == $text6 )
   {
   mysql_query("insert into contactus values('$name','$email','$message')");
   echo "S";
  }

Comment: $session6 is captcha image and text6 is the captcha textbox